# Maximum of Series' means with panda

Tags: python, pandas, header, max, mean

I've been searching for a while now and I can't figure out how to do that in other way than hardcoding it.
In a csv file, I have to obtain the maximum value of the mean of three series, and then return the NAME of that series, which is the part causing me troubles.

```
comp = max(DataTD['Cycle (seconds)'].mean(), DataTD['Run (seconds)'].mean(), DataTD['Swim (seconds)'].mean())
if comp == DataTD['Cycle (seconds)'].mean():
    print(DataTD['Cycle (seconds)'].name)
elif comp == DataTD['Run (seconds)'].mean():
    print(DataTD['Run (seconds)'].name)
elif comp == DataTD['Swim (seconds)'].mean():
    print(DataTD['Swim (seconds)'].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (haven't test it):

```
datas = [DataTD['Cycle (seconds)'],
         DataTD['Run (seconds)'],
         DataTD['Swim (seconds)']]
means = [data.mean() for data in datas]
max_mean_idx = np.argmax(means)
print(datas[max_mean_idx].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum column name, then based on that grab the mean.

```
cols = ['Cycle (seconds)', 'Run (seconds)', 'Swim (seconds)']

max_col = max(cols, key=lambda col: DataTD[col].mean())
print('Column name: ' + max_col)
print('Mean: ' + str(DataTD[max_col].mean()))
```

Comment: I think you need to define the key as a function like: `key=lambda col: DataTD[col].mean()`. also `col` should be `max_col`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sample data

```
cols = ['Cycle (seconds)', 'Run (seconds)', 'Swim (seconds)']

np.random.seed([3, 1415])

DataTD = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)),
    list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), cols
)

   Cycle (seconds)  Run (seconds)  Swim (seconds)
A                0              2               7
B                3              8               7
C                0              6               8
D                6              0               2
E                0              4               9
F                7              3               2
G                4              3               3
H                6              7               7
I                4              5               3
J                7              5               9
```

---

IIUC:

Use `mean` with argument `axis=1` followed with an `idxmax` to find the index for the maximal value.

```
DataTD.loc[[DataTD[cols].mean(1).idxmax()]]

   Cycle (seconds)  Run (seconds)  Swim (seconds)
J                7              5               9
```

Otherwise, try

```
means = DataTD.mean()
means[[means.idxmax()]]

Swim (seconds)    5.7
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Data  From Pir

```
DataTD.loc[DataTD[cols].mean(1).sort_values().iloc[[-1]].index]
Out[625]: 
   Cycle (seconds)  Run (seconds)  Swim (seconds)
J                7              5               9
```